# Why did the Spectrum Next choose Z80 on FPGA?

Tags: z80, zx-spectrum, design-choices, diy-computing

I'm curious to understand why the Spectrum Next uses Z80 on an FPGA instead of something like at eZ80?  I would have imagined they would choose the eZ80 since it is still a production part.  Anyone know the underlying thinking?

Comment: may be because of compatibility as newer CPUs versions tend to have different timings and timing is critical in 8bit computing ... so different one might break many effects in games even crash ... However I did not cross check datasheets those are just my assumptions.

Comment: Spektre is right. But also, the eZ80 is not compatible with the ZX Spectrum because it uses port FE for its own purpose.

Comment: @OmarL - Do you have a reference for the eZ80 using 0xFE? I have found links to the [Spectum's use of 0xFE](https://worldofspectrum.org/faq/reference/48kreference.htm), but nothing for the eZ80. Sorry to ask in a comment, I *could* post a real question, if you'd prefer...

Comment: @Greenonline I have no reference, it's been a while. I'd encourage you to ask a question though, I'd be happy to read it

Comment: @OmarL - https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21832/202